# Why is the answer to this code being printed 3 times on each number until it is right?

Tags: c

There is something really wrong about how this code turned out.
Basically I want to print the sum of numbers divided by 3 until 20.
It is doing what I am asking it to do, but it is printing each addition 3 times for some reason when all I want is for it to print the final result once!
Help me please thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i=1;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=1;i<21;i++){
        if(i%3 == 0)
        sum += i;
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is because it prints in every iteration. It adds to `sum` in every 3rd iteration, and prints in every iteration.

Comment: If you want to print `sum` at the end why is the `printf` call inside of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Indenting properly to show flow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i=1;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=1;i<21;i++){
        if(i%3 == 0)
            sum += i;
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This better shows that only your `sum += i` is within the `if`.

TO address the first part of your question, the additional prints of each number are removed by using curly braces:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i=1;
    int sum=0;
    for (i=1;i<21;i++) {
        if (i%3 == 0) {
            sum += i;
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If an `if` statement contains more than one statement, you need to use curly braces to enclose the block. In general, omitting braces with `if`, `for`, `while`, etc. blocks is dangerous because adding a statement will not cause it to be included.

Always properly indent your code, it helps catch errors like these before they happen.

---

The second part of your question involves only printing the final result. You have the printing within the loop, so it will happen every time the condition is true.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i=1;
    int sum=0;
    for (i=1;i<21;i++) {
        if (i%3 == 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It fixed the print for 3 times but I really just want the final result xD. Thank you though.

Comment: @SudarZGracer Why is the `printf` within the loop if that's your goal?

Comment: @SudarZGracer I've updated my answer with the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot the "{" and "}" because of the tabs. It make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `printf` outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement has no curly braces, so it affects only the next line. You only accumulate in sum if it's divisible byt 3, but the printf is being executed in all instancnes of the loop.

You should surround the if block within curly braces:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i=1;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=1;i<21;i++){
        if(i%3 == 0){
            sum += i;
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a different note, summing up all positive integers divisble by `k`, less than or equal to `n*k` can be done closed form with `k*n*(n + 1)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

"*...When all I want is for it to print the final result once!*"

Why do you use `printf("%d\n", sum);` then inside of the loop?

```
for (i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    sum += i;
    printf("%d\n", sum);
}
```

should be

```
for (i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    sum += i;
}

printf("%d\n", sum);
```